# How can I install Opendtect?

Tags: installation

The [Opendtect project](http://www.opendtect.org/) is open source and still I have problems with the installation. When I run the installer, it does open a terminal for a second and then disappears. It has no manuals and few topics, the installation manual is not clear at all either.

So, how do I install Opendtect in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a Terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install csh
cd
wget http://opendtect.org/relman/OpendTect_Installer_lux32.sh
chmod a+x OpendTect_Installer_lux32.sh
./OpendTect_Installer_lux32.sh
```

This will install the C shell, which is needed to run the OpendTect installer.

Then the installer is fetched and saved to your home directory, marked as executable, and executed.

Comment: Glad it worked well :)